# Validating login form using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm relatively new to HTML and JS and I've been trying to create a simple login page that on entering valid credentials redirects to index.html page. But no matter what I enter it always redirects to the index.html page. Here's the HTML code for the login page

```
<form role="form" action="index.html" name="formlogin" method="post" class="login-form" onsubmit="check_info()">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="form-username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" name="form-username" placeholder="Username..." class="form-username form-control" id="form-username">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="form-password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="form-password" placeholder="Password..." class="form-password form-control" id="form-password">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn" value="submit">Sign in!</button>
</form>
```

Here's the javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function check_info()
{
var myform = document.formlogin;

    if(myform.form-username.value == "test")
    {
        if(myform.form-password.value == "123")
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

P.S: I'm using a bootstrap login template.

Comment: It's happenning because when you submit, the `action`parameter in form is been called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Html:

```
onsubmit="return check_info()"
```

Javascript:

```
function check_info()
{
var user = document.getElementById("form-username").value;
var pass = document.getElementById("form-password").value;
    if(user == "test")
    {
        if(pass == "123")
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use required parameter like this:

```
<input type="text" name="form-username" placeholder="Username..." class="form-username form-control" id="form-username" required>
```

Comment: Whatever you have after "this:" isn't visible. You need to format your HTML as code.